# When I click the button , the page is going up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help.I'm trying to find a solution about my problem. When i click the button,the page will to go up, but i don't want this.The page have to stay, after the clicking. Here is my code below;

```
<section class="category">
  <h1 class="uppercase">OTURMA ODASI</h1>
  <ul class="ad-list sub">
    <li>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="#" class="subMenuOpener">
          <img src="images/content/icon/tire.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span>OTURMA GRUPLARI</span>
        </a>
        <ul style="display: block;" class="sub-ul">
          <li class="sub-li">
            <a href="oturma-odasi-mobilyalari/oturma-gruplari-takimlari/koltuk-takimlari-mobilyalari.html">
              <img src="images/content/icon/oturma_koltuk_takimlari.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span class="no-content">KOLTUK TAKIMLARI</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-li">
            <a href="oturma-odasi-mobilyalari/oturma-gruplari-takimlari/kose-koltuklar-mobilyalar.html">
              <img src="images/content/icon/oturma_kose_koltuklar.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span class="no-content">KÖŞE KOLTUKLAR</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="#" class="subMenuOpener">
          <img src="images/content/icon/tire.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span>SEHPALAR</span>
        </a>
        <ul style="display: block;" class="sub-ul">
          <li class="sub-li">
            <a href="oturma-odasi-mobilyalari/orta-zigon-yan-sehpalar-mobilyalar/zigon-sehpa.html">
              <img src="images/content/icon/sehpazigon.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span class="no-content">ZİGON SEHPA</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-li">
            <a href="oturma-odasi-mobilyalari/orta-zigon-yan-sehpalar-mobilyalar/yan-sehpa.html">
              <img src="images/content/icon/sehpalar_yan_sehpa.svg" alt="img-description" height="48" width="48"><span class="no-content">YAN SEHPA</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Thanks for everything

Comment: are you refering to the `<a>`'s as buttons?

Comment: Set "javascript:;" instead of "#" in a href.

Comment: @JacobGray yes, i refering to <a> as buttons.

Comment: @mfrkndgn then follow Cosmin's answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of things like `<a href="#" ....` use `<a href="javascript:void(1);" ....`

`#` in conjunction with a valid base href has this unwanted scrolling effect.

Comment: @mfrkndgn It must work. If this doesn't work it means the scrolling is coming from somewhere else, like a js scroll or en element opens then another scroll is made.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jquery, so you have to prevent the default. See the following approach:

```
$('section.category ul li a').on('click', function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal link action

   // do your alternative logic
});
```

Reliable documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/